# How to pick a key with the highest value

Tags: python

heres an example code of what I have

```
my_dict = {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':3, 'd':8, 'e':3}
```

How could i make it print the key that has the highest value. For example in the above code it would print:

```
d
```

thats all i would want to be printed, just the key that had the highest value.
help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use a key with max

```
max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
my_dict = {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':3, 'd':8, 'e':3}
max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
=> 'd'
```

Notice that `max` can find the maximum value of any iterable passed as parameter, and the optional key argument specifies a one-argument selector function for determining what's the attribute in each of the objects to be used for finding the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(my_dict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different than the others:

```
d = {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':3, 'd':8, 'e':3}
new_d = {d[i]:i for i in d.keys()} # reverses the dict {'a': 2} --> {2: 'a'}
new_d[max(new_d.keys())]
```